# Alias nested struct columns

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I alias field1 as index & & field 2 as value

The query gives me an error:

```
#standardsql
with q1 as (select 1 x, ARRAY<struct<id string, cd ARRAY<STRUCT<index STRING,value STRING>>>>
                    [struct('h1',[('1','a')
                                 ,('2','b')
                                 ])
                          ,('h2',[('3','c')
                                 ,('4','d')
                                 ])] hits
       )


Select * from q1
ORDER by x

Error: Array element type STRUCT<STRING, ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, STRING>>> does not coerce to STRUCT<id STRING, cd ARRAY<STRUCT<index STRING, value STRING>>> at [5:26]
```

Thanks a lot for your time in responding

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
#standardsql
WITH q1 AS (
  SELECT 
    1 AS x, 
      [
        STRUCT('h1' AS id, [STRUCT('1' AS index, 'a' AS value), ('2','b')] AS cd), 
        STRUCT('h2', [STRUCT('3' AS index, 'c' AS value), ('4','d')] AS cd)
      ] AS hits
)
SELECT * 
FROM q1
-- ORDER BY x
```

or below might be even more "readable"

```sql
#standardsql
WITH q1 AS (
  SELECT 
    1 AS x, 
      [
        STRUCT('h1' AS id, [STRUCT<index STRING, value STRING>('1', 'a'), ('2','b')] AS cd), 
        STRUCT('h2', [STRUCT<index STRING, value STRING>('3', 'c'), ('4','d')] AS cd)
      ] AS hits
)
SELECT * 
FROM q1
-- ORDER BY x
```

Comment: Thanks, this help me to iterate over my original query

Answer (score 1):

When I try to simulate data in BigQuery using the Standard Version I usually try to name all variables and aliases everywhere possible. For instance, your data works if you build it like so:

```
with q1 as (
select 1 x, ARRAY<struct<id string, cd ARRAY<STRUCT<index STRING,value STRING>>>>  [struct('h1' as id,[STRUCT('1' as index,'a' as value) ,STRUCT('2' as index ,'b' as value)] as cd), STRUCT('h2',[STRUCT('3' as index,'c' as value) ,STRUCT('4' as index,'d' as value)] as cd)] hits
)

select * from q1
order by x
```

Notice I've built structs and put aliases inside of them in order for this to work (if you remove the aliases and the structs it might not work, but I found that this seems to be rather intermittent. If you fully describe the variables then it works all the time).

Also as a recommendation, I try to build simulated data piece by piece. First I create the struct and test it to see if BigQuery accepts it. After the validator is green, then I proceed to add more values. If you try to build everything at once you might find this a somewhat challenging task.

Comment: Thanks, this help me to iterate over my original query